# Profiling tool for HTML, PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is there any free profiling tool with which I can measure the performance of HTML, PHP and JavaScript code independently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the performance of PHP I use [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) with [cachegrind](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) turned on.  For HTML and Javascript I like to use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) / [yslow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5369).

Answer (score 2):

For html/javascript try:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

this link has 2 tools.  Firebug (profile your javascript). and YSlow testing page load times and gives you suggestions on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If your php pages are using a database, your queries will almost certainly be the most expensive part of any request. And that gets worse with time as your dataset grows.